# Images are not displaying properly in textview

Tags: android

I am trying to display html content with some images in a textview. The problem is the images are overlaping text. Here is the code. can any one help me please.

here htmldata is string that contains html data .

```
                String htmldata="<here html data comes>";//html data comes from  ws                     
                URLImageParser p = new URLImageParser(tv_body, this);
            Spanned htmlSpan = Html.fromHtml(htmldata, p, null);
        tv_body.setText(htmlSpan);


             public class URLDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
    // the drawable that you need to set, you could set the initial drawing
    // with the loading image if you need to
    protected Drawable drawable;

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        // override the draw to facilitate refresh function later
        if(drawable != null) {
            drawable.draw(canvas);

        }
    }
}
public class URLImageParser implements ImageGetter {
    Context c;
    View container;

    /***
     * Construct the URLImageParser which will execute AsyncTask and refresh the                              container
     * @param t
     * @param c
     */
    public URLImageParser(View t, Context c) {
        this.c = c;
        this.container = t;
    }

    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        URLDrawable urlDrawable = new URLDrawable();

        // get the actual source
        ImageGetterAsyncTask asyncTask = 
            new ImageGetterAsyncTask( urlDrawable);

        asyncTask.execute(source);

        // return reference to URLDrawable where I will change with actual image from
        // the src tag
        return urlDrawable;
    }

    public class ImageGetterAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable>  {
        URLDrawable urlDrawable;

        public ImageGetterAsyncTask(URLDrawable d) {
            this.urlDrawable = d;
        }

        @Override
        protected Drawable doInBackground(String... params) {
            String source = params[0];
            System.out.println("source==="+source);
            return fetchDrawable(source);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
            // set the correct bound according to the result from HTTP call

            // System.out.println("result.getIntrinsicWidth()==="+result.getIntrinsicWidth());
            // System.out.println("result.getIntrinsicHeight()==="+result.getIntrinsicHeight());
             if(result!=null)
             {
            urlDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + result.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0 
                    + result.getIntrinsicHeight()); 
             }

            // change the reference of the current drawable to the result
            // from the HTTP call
            urlDrawable.drawable = result;

            // redraw the image by invalidating the container
            URLImageParser.this.container.invalidate();
        }

        /***
         * Get the Drawable from URL
         * @param urlString
         * @return
         */
        public Drawable fetchDrawable(String urlString) {
            try {
                InputStream is = fetch(urlString);
                Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
                if(drawable!=null){
                drawable.setBounds(0,0, 0 + drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0 
                        + drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()); 
                }
                else
                {
                    drawable=null;
                }
                return drawable;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {

    if(result!=null)
    {
        urlDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + result.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0 
        + result.getIntrinsicHeight()); 
    }

    urlDrawable.drawable = result;

    URLImageParser.this.container.invalidate();

    //add this
    URLImageParser.this.container.setText(URLImageParser.this.container.getText());
}
```